# Query object created by express 4.17.1,nothing in req.body

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently using Express ^4.17.1.

I am trying to make sense of url encoded queries. The behaviour I see doesn't match my understanding of the express specs. According to the specs http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html, using `express.urlencoded`:

> A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware (i.e. req.body), or an empty object ({})

BUT with an original url of this type:

`req.originalUrl: /users/status?a=1234&b=5678`

I end up with this:

`req.body: {}`

`req.query: {"a":"1234","b":"5678"}`

My code implements express as follows:

`const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '3MB' }));
app.use(express.json({ limit: '3MB' }));`

The req.query object contains what I would expect in req.body, why is req.body empty? Do I need to nullify the express app's query parser for queries to end in req.body instead? How do I do that?

If express contains a query parser by default, why add support for express.urlencoded, do you get access to different kind of queries with these two tools?

---

**Edit 5/11/2020**
This question came from my lack of knowledge of http.

The urlencoded module is used to decode body data which has been encoded as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. All this means is that the body section has been encoded in the same way the url section is (please someone correct me if I'm wrong!). But it doesn't link the body section to the url in any way.

So req.body is empty because I'm not passing any body in my GET call. And the query details are indeed fetched from req.query.

Comment: you are passing the data as params url, not by the body of the request, that's why your req.body is empty

Comment: @maxi: right, but express.urlencoded should place the request object in req.body? Per the specs req.body "Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as express.json() or express.urlencoded()."

Answer (score 1):

You can run your query like this:

```
const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      body: JSON.stringify( { a: 1234, b: 5678 } ),
    };

fetch(`${originalUrl}`, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm actually trying to understand how to properly handle url based queries, not rely on the body section... So I am trying to understand if the express.urlencoded has anything to do with this. Reading on x-www-form-urlencoded right now...

Comment: So to be clear I intended for my query to be formatted as it is in my question :-)

Comment: @Will59 I changed my answer with headers 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. I understand you, but express.urlencoded decodes the data that is encoded in x-www-form-urlencoded. if I have helped you can you vote up for my answer please?